# Find the volume of the region under $1+x+x^5$ and above $[0,1]$ that is revolved around the y axis

Tags: calculus

I am trying to find the volume of the region under $1+x+x^5$ and above $[0,1]$ that is revolved around the y axis using disk method(not shell or anything else).

I tried to calculate the volume of the whole cylinder considering the radius of 1 and the height of 3 and then subtract the upper(inner) part from it.

I obtained the volume of he upper part by changing the $1+x+x^5$ to $1+y+y^5$ to obtain the formula for the radius of the upper part. However, when I subtracted the volume of the bigger cylinder from the inner part I get a minus result. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

(Sorry I am not good with producing digital graphs. otherwise I would provide it here.)

Comment: Your error is going from $1+x+x^5$ to $1+y+y^5$. Instead, use the equation $y=1+x+x^5$ and solve for $y$.

Comment: What's $[0, 1]$? Can you specify what area you want?

Comment: Is [this](http://i.imgur.com/IVSzkPK.png) what you're trying to describe? So you want to calculate the volume generated by rotating the green shape around the $y$ axis, and then subtract that from the volume of a cylinder of radius $1$ and height $3$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you know, the region whose volume you are seeking is a cylinder, base radius $1$, height $3$, minus what you called the inner part. The cylinder has volume $3\pi$.

By the Method of Slicing (Disks) the volume of the inner part is 
$$\int_{y=1}^3 \pi x^2\,dy.$$
Solving for $x$ in terms of $y$ is (almost) hopeless. However, to evaluate the integral we can make the **substitution** $y=1+x+x^5$. Then $dy=(1+5x^4)\,dx$, and as $y$ travels from $1$ to $3$, $x$ travels from $0$ to $1$. Thus the volume of the inner part is
$$\int_{x=0}^1 \pi x^2 (1+5x^4)\,dx.$$
The integration is uneventful. We get $\frac{22}{21}\pi$, so the desired volume is $\frac{41}{21}\pi$.

**Remark:** The (forbidden) Shell method is somewhat easier, but not all that much easier. This is an interesting problem. A suitable generalization will show that the choice of method (Shells or Slicing) is not as critical as first calculus courses make it appear.